# Error message comes up when I say localhost:3000

Tags: reactjs, localhost

When I put localhost:3000 into the address bar an error message comes up saying:

This site can’t be reached

**localhost** refused to connect.

Try:

- Checking the connection
- Checking the proxy and the firewall

ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

What am I doing wrong? Has anyone else had this same problem? I am working with react in visual studio code.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KE6mi.png

Comment: Did you start your app by running npm run start?

Comment: I have never worked with react before, so I'm not quite sure of what I'm doing, sorry. I just tried to do npm run start and the terminal gave me an error message saying:

Comment: > Constance-VanWoerkom-React-Portfolio@1.0.0 start C:\Users\rscot\Desktop\Constance-VanWoerkom-React-Portfolio
> webpack-dev-server --config webpack/dev.config.js --watch
'webpack-dev-server' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! Constance-VanWoerkom-React-Portfolio@1.0.0 start: `webpack-dev-server --config webpack/dev.config.js --watch`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the Constance-VanWoerkom-React-Portfolio@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

Comment: @ShmiliBreuer Oh! I just fixed it! Thank you so much! You were right, I need to do npm run start. I had to do npm install, and then npm start, and then it said that it was running on localhost:3000. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran `npm run start`, which I had forgotten to do. After I did this, I got a bunch of errors, so in order to fix that I did `npm install` first and then `npm start`.